# How to re-run the case statement if the input is invalid?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, case

I have the following code in the middle of a script to confirm whether we want to resume the script or not.

```
read -r -p "Would you like to continue  [Y/N] : " i
case $i in
        [yY])
                echo -e "Resuming the script";;
        [nN])
                echo -e "Skipped and exit script"
                exit 1;;
        *)
                echo "Invalid Option"
                ;;
esac
```

I would like to know is there any way to know is there any way to recall the switch-case if the input option is invalid?

Comment: You need to rerun the switch case if the input is other than `Y and N`, am i right?

Comment: Sivaprasath, Yes

Comment: Use functions from the main level of your script so that you can control flow more easily.

Comment: If it's bash, you can use `select` statement - that one doesn't exit until you have valid input, IIRC

Answer (score 15):

Do your input in a loop. Exit the loop with `break` (or `exit` as the case may be) if you get a valid response from the user.

```
while true; do
    read -p 'Continue? yes/no: ' input
    case $input in
        [yY]*)
            echo 'Continuing'
            break
            ;;
        [nN]*)
            echo 'Ok, exiting'
            exit 1
            ;;
         *)
            echo 'Invalid input' >&2
    esac
done
```

As a utility function:

```
ask_continue () {
    while true; do
        read -p 'Continue? yes/no: ' input        
        case $input in
            [yY]*)
                echo 'Continuing'
                break
                ;;
            [nN]*)
                echo 'Ok, exiting'
                exit 1
                ;;
             *)
                echo 'Invalid input' >&2
        esac
    done
}
```

A variation of the utility function that allows exiting through EOF (e.g. pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>):

```
ask_continue () {
    while read -p 'Continue? yes/no: ' input; do    
        case $input in
            [yY]*)
                echo 'Continuing'
                return
                ;;
            [nN]*)
                break
                ;;
             *)
                echo 'Invalid input' >&2
        esac
    done

    echo 'Ok, exiting'
    exit 1
}
```

Here, there are three ways out of the loop:

1. The user enters "yes", in which case the function returns.
2. The user enters "no", in which case the we `break` out of the loop and execute `exit 1`.
3. The `read` fails due to something like encountering an end-of-input or some other error, in which case the `exit 1` is executed.

Instead of `exit 1` you may want to use `return 1` to allow tho caller to decide what to do when the user does not want to continue.  The calling code may then look like

```
if ! ask_continue; then
    # some cleanup, then exit
fi
```

Comment: You may also want to exit the script upon empty input (EOF).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, definitely. I'll update in the morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just repeating the read?

```
unset i
while [[ ! "$i" =~ ^[yYnN]$ ]]; do read -r -p "Would you like to continue  [Y/N] : " i; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do by keeping switch case inside a function.

```
function testCase ()
{
    read -r -p "Would you like to continue  [Y/N] : " i
    case $i in
        [yY])
            echo -e "Resuming the script";;
        [nN])
            echo -e "Skipped and exit script"
            exit 1;;
        *)
            echo "Invalid Option"
            testCase
            ;;
    esac
}
testCase
```

If the input is invalid it will recall the function until it gets a valid input.

Comment: Or until you run into a resource restriction or a maximum recursion depth limit.

Comment: I wouldn't count on the shell being able to optimize the tail recursion, and given the usual procedural nature of shell scripts, I'd really suggest writing that loop out.

Comment: @Kusalananda If the user gives an incorrect answer to a simple yes/no question so many times you hit the recursion limit, he deserves to have the script crash.

Comment: @Barmar A programmer should expect that the user will input _anything_, whether it's an incorrect answer enough times to hit a recursion limit, or eight gigabytes of null and control codes. Failing on a corner case like this is indicative of bad programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
until [ "$i" = "0" ]
do
read -r -p "Would you like to continue  [Y/N] : " i
case $i in
        [yY])
                echo -e "Resuming the script";;
        [nN])
                echo -e "Skipped and exit script"
                exit 1;;
        *)
                echo "Invalid Option"
                ;;
esac
done
```